# Outputing search results in Codeiginter

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, codeigniter

Hi I have a search result page that outputs all the information from my search like I want it to but I only have one little problem I does not retrieve the image of the "property". Currently my database has a property table and a property_images table all the information about the property is stored in the property table and the images in the property_images table.

My upload function uses the insert_id to add the images to the specified property_images table and link it to the property.

My question is this, if I create a property_image field in the property table how would I get the output to display only one image from the property_image table or how would I add the image_id to the property table so that I can output the one image in my search?

Here is my search code:

```
    function get_search(){
        $property_location = $this->input->post('property_location');
        $property_bedroom = $this->input->post('property_bedroom');
        $property_bathroom = $this->input->post('property_bathroom');
        $property_status = $this->input->post('property_status');
        $property_type = $this->input->post('property_type');

        $this->db->like('property_location',$property_location);
        $this->db->like('property_beds',$property_bedroom);
        $this->db->like('property_bath',$property_bathroom);
        $this->db->like('property_state',$property_status);
        $this->db->like('property_type',$property_type);
        $query = $this->db->get('property');
        error_log($this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

And my upload code

```
 private function setup_upload_option()
{
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './data/images/property_images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    return $config;
}

function create_property()
{
    $this->check_is_validated();
    $data['error'] = array('error' => '');
    $files = $_FILES;
    $prop = array(
        'property_ref' => $this->input->post('property_ref'),
        'property_name' => $this->input->post('property_name'),
        'property_slug' => $this->input->post('property_slug'),
        'property_type' => $this->input->post('property_type'),
        'property_state' => $this->input->post('property_state'),
        'property_price' => $this->input->post('property_price'),
        'property_address' => $this->input->post('property_address'),
        'property_description' => $this->input->post('property_description'),
        'active' => 1
    );

    $cap = $this->db->insert('property', $prop);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    if ($cap > 0) {

        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['userfile']['error'][$i];

            $this->upload->initialize($this->setup_upload_option());
            if ($this->upload->do_upload() == FALSE) {
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $data['title'] = 'Create a New Property';
                $data['content'] = 'admin' . '/property/create_new_property';
                $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/template', $data);
            } else {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $data = array(
                    'image_id' => $id,
                    'image_name' => $upload_data['file_name'],
                    'image_size' => $upload_data['file_size'],
                    'image_ext' => $upload_data['file_ext'],
                    'full_path' => $upload_data['file_path']
                );
                $this->db->insert('property_images', $data);
            }
        }
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/properties');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help, at least try to make it at first place.. If you fail, show us your CODE and we can help you then ..

Comment: I have already made it like I said the search works, all I want to know is can I in the database add image_id in the property_image field...will that work?

Comment: please add code. Reading content is so boring

Comment: @Abdulla okay agreed :-)

Comment: Are you showing property list or properties in grid view?

Comment: @siddhesh This is how the current output looks [hollowaypropertiesdolphincoast.co.za] just click on search

Comment: Is your question is how to fetch one image for every property?

Comment: basically yes but the search query does not join the property_images table to the query